# Add a clickable link at a specific page and location of a PDF file to open another local pdf file in a new window using PyPDF2(or any python library)

Tags: python, pdf

I am trying to add a clickable link (at a specific page and location) to an existing pdf file.
When users click the link, I want to open another pdf file in the same folder for users.

The following is my code segment on MacOS. However, it can generate a pdf file with a link. But when I click the link, it sometimes pop out a window to say "cannot find the file", sometimes just no response. (btw, it I change the uri to an internet hyperlink, it really can open the website on Chrome)

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
reader = PdfReader("linkTest.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()
for page in reader.pages:
    writer.add_page(page)
writer.add_uri(
    pagenum=0,
    page_number = 1,
    uri="file:///air.pdf",
    
    rect=(10, 10, 100, 50)
)
with open("linkTestOut.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

I also find some other resources, but I still cannot make it.

for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65890101/how-to-add-a-relative-file-path-inside-a-pdf-using-pypdf#new-answer?newreg=9bc8b21b31e741bcbf9ca28f902725f4)

this is a potential solution.
However, the code segment is not runnable and a little bit difficult to understand.

Any suggestions

Thanks,
Bests,
KC

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer.

```py
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import PageLayout, SingleColumnLayout
from borb.pdf import Paragraph
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.annotation.remote_go_to_annotation import RemoteGoToAnnotation


def main():

    # create empty Document
    doc: Document = Document()

    # create empty Page and add it to Document
    page: Page = Page()
    doc.add_page(page)

    # use a PageLayout to avoid having to calculate where
    # content needs to be placed
    layout: PageLayout = SingleColumnLayout(page)
 
    # add a Paragraph, using its default font, size, color, etc
    p: Paragraph = Paragraph("Hello World")
    layout.add(p)

    # add a RemoteGoToAnnotation
    # using the paint box of the Paragraph
    page.add_annotation(RemoteGoToAnnotation(p.get_previous_paint_box(),
                                             "output_001.pdf"
                                       ))

    # store the PDF
    with open("output_002.pdf", "wb") as fh:
        PDF.dumps(fh, doc)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This example creates a very simple PDF, containing one paragraph of text.
The coordinates of the paragraph are used to add a `RemoteGoToAnnotation`,
which takes as arguments a bounding box, and a URL.